# How to suppress certain parts of gud-gdb -i=mi output in gud buffer?

Tags: gdb, gud

I start gdb in emacs with 'gdb' command. Is there a way to hide certain lines from being shown in gud buffer?
For example, when I do C-c C-c on a running program, I see the following in the buffer:

```
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x0000555555555182 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf58) at test.cpp:6
6     for ( i=0;i<2000000000;++i){
```

Is there any way I can configure emacs to show a shorter string instead, for example
"Interrupt test.cpp:6"?

Comment: Sure, I modified the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to add advice for gud-gdbmi-marker-filter arguments:

```
(defun my_filter (string)
  "Filter out certain messages from GDB-MI."
  (progn
   ; (message (nth 0 string))
  (if (string-match  "pattern"
        (nth 0 string))
           (list nil) string)))

(advice-add 'gud-gdbmi-marker-filter :filter-args 'my_filter)
```

pattern here is regualr expression for what needs to be filtered. I think I had some glitches with it, and after all I didn't need this, but I hope this may help somebody else in future.